# not able to install Baidu-Analytics-SDK or Baidu-Maps-iOS-SDK cocoapod

Tags: ios, sdk, cocoapods, zip, baidu

No matter I edit the version or update cocoapods, I get the below error. I have seen people facing the same error on forums, but is there any workaround for this:

Installing Baidu-Analytics-SDK (3.0)

[!] Error installing Baidu-Analytics-SDK
[!] /usr/bin/unzip /var/folders/xy/mt3d95xj4t739cx2pq491gnm0000gn/T/d20170114-1208-jyb88w/file.zip -d /var/folders/xy/mt3d95xj4t739cx2pq491gnm0000gn/T/d20170114-1208-jyb88w

Archive:  /var/folders/xy/mt3d95xj4t739cx2pq491gnm0000gn/T/d20170114-1208-jyb88w/file.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /var/folders/xy/mt3d95xj4t739cx2pq491gnm0000gn/T/d20170114-1208-jyb88w/file.zip or
        /var/folders/xy/mt3d95xj4t739cx2pq491gnm0000gn/T/d20170114-1208-jyb88w/file.zip.zip, and cannot find /var/folders/xy/mt3d95xj4t739cx2pq491gnm0000gn/T/d20170114-1208-jyb88w/file.zip.ZIP, period.

If there is an alternate way to use this, then please let me know.. Else i have stumbled upon an alternate pod in a private repository. And this issue should be reported to cocoapods so they can remove this not working pod from their directory.

Comment: Anyone, I can't afford a bounty :)

Comment: did u get any solution?

Comment: pod 'BaiduMapKit'

Comment: thanks for your help. Actually I dont want to use BaiduMapKit in my project. Do you mean analytics features can be used if I install BaiduMapKit? So there is no alternative solution?

Comment: no pod till date for analytics. i have downloaded the sdk from baidu site where we register our bundleid for analytics

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is the solution

just try,

```
pod install 'BaiduAnalytics'
```

instead of

```
pod install 'Baidu-Analytics-SDK'
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone tries to install the Baidu SDK using cocoa pod then follow the following steps :

1. Open terminal
2. Go to your project directory
3. pod init
4. Open the pod file created in your project directory
5. Write the following lines in the pod file

`platform : ios, '10.0'`

```
target “BaiduAnalyticsTestApp” do
   pod 'BaiduAnalytics'
end
```

6. Then save it and run `pod install`

Hope this will help others too. Download link : https://mtj.baidu.com/web/sdk/index